# How to change the color and separation of fillstyle=vlines and \fillstyle=hlines PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks

I am doing a figure and I want to fill a polygon with `fillstyle=vlines` or `fillstyle=hlines` but I want this filling in a different color to the black which is what throws by default. Besides this, I also want to change the separation between the lines. How can I do this?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-poly}
\usepackage{pst-fill}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(6,6)
\pspolygon[fillstyle=vlines](1,1)(1,4)(4,4)(4,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to change the color of the command `vlines`.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 4):

Just 4 fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i/\c in {1/red,2/green,3/blue,4/magenta,5/cyan,6/orange,7/black,8/yellow,9/pink,10/gray}{%
\begin{pspicture}(6,6)
    \psframe[fillstyle=vlines,hatchcolor=\c,hatchsep=\i pt](6,6)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For instance:

```
\pspolygon[fillstyle=hlines, hatchcolor=blue,hatchsep=6pt]...
```

or, if you want to set it for all what you want to fill:

```
\psset{fillstyle=hlines, hatchcolor=blue,hatchsep=6pt}
```

The other parameters re explained in § 14 of `pstuser.doc`(version 1.5, 2007). Here is a summary:

`hatchwidth = …` defines the lines thickness (default 0.8pt)

`hatchsep` defaults to 4pt.

`hatchangle = …` defines the angle of the hatch lines with the horizontal (for hlines) or vertical direction (for vlines). It defaults to 45, so that hlines are oriented SW-NE.
and vlines are oriented NW-SE.

`fillcolor = …` defines the background color. You can use color expression from the `xcolor` package.

Comment: It's `\psset`, not `\pset`.

Comment: @Svend Tveskæd:  Sorry for the typo. Corrected.